# How can I call a function when an MKPlacemark is clicked in MapView (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mkplacemark

I am trying to perform a certain function whenever an MKPlacemark is clicked on my MapView. This function pulls information from the placemark and displays it on a separate view. I have tried to use

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {}
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if I have to name each placemark, I have avoided doing so because I am already displaying location data in the name (as can be seen in my code). Any help would be much appreciated. My code:

Initiating the placemark (this happens numerous times, the variables have already been instantiated):

```
let coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latOfPlace!, lonOfPlace!)
let address = [CNPostalAddressStreetKey: addressStreetKey, CNPostalAddressCityKey: addressCityKey, CNPostalAddressPostalCodeKey: addressPostalCodeKey, CNPostalAddressISOCountryCodeKey: addressISOCountryCodeKey]
let place = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coords, addressDictionary: address)
self.mapView.addAnnotation(place)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the delegate inside `viewDidLoad`

```
self.mapView.delegate = self
```

---

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
  guard let ann = view.annotation as? MKPlacemark else { return }
  print(ann)
}
```

Comment: where do I declare self.mapView.delegate = self?

Comment: inside viewDidLoad